# write a regular expression expression for the set of strings over alphabet {a,b,c) containing at least one a and at least one b

Tags: theory, formal-languages, computation

> write a regular expression expression for the set of strings over alphabet {a,b,c) containing at least one a and at least one b

How can I answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

`E*(aE*b)|(bE*a)E*`

`E` is sigma, so any character in the alphabet

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment on joeya17's answer, but I don't see how that Regex would accept the string "abc" or "cba".

I came up with this Regex initially:

```
( a+b+c* U a+c*b+ U b+a+c* U b+c*a+ U c*+a+b+ U c*b+a+ )+
```

which I think should work, but seeing joeya17's answer, I think you could do it like this as well:

```
E = any letter in Sigma
(E*a+E*b+|a+E*b+E*|b+E*a+E*|E*b+E*a+)+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
For the regular expression there are various possibilities:-
Now,
exactly one a and one b (where a comes before b) - c* a c* b c*
exactly one a and one b (where b comes before a) - c* b c* a c*
We take this idea to the answer for more than one a and b:-
a comes before b
(c* a a* c* b b* c*) ;
b comes before a
(c* b b* c* a a* c*)
or there are intermmediate occurances of a and b :-
Let RE R=(a+b+c)* 
this is all possible occurences of a,b,c in all orders ;
Hence when a comes before b;
(R* a R* b R*);
when b comes before a;
(R* b R* a B*)

we take the union to get the final answer ( R* a R* b R* + R* b R* a R*) where R = (a + b + c)*
```